# loading program with irb when using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, irb

I am creating a simple program of blackjack with ruby. I am doing this to work on my TDD skills therefore i am using Rspec for test coverage. In order to keep the work cleaner the structure of my files is a main folder called blackjack. Within this are lib and spec folders. Within the lib so far have a deck.rb and card.rb files. I then have retrospective spec folders for each. I am running into so problems when i try and load the program in irb. I am a bit confused if i want to test methods that are split between the two folders how should i go about this. When loading the deck and card files individually i get the following errors.

```
2.1.1 :001 > require "./deck.rb"
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > cards = Deck.build_cards
NameError: uninitialized constant Deck::Card
    from /Users/em/ruby/blackjack/lib/deck.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in build_cards'
    from /Users/em/ruby/blackjack/lib/deck.rb:6:in `each'
    from /Users/em/ruby/blackjack/lib/deck.rb:6:in `block in build_cards'
    from /Users/em/ruby/blackjack/lib/deck.rb:5:in `each'
    from /Users/em/ruby/blackjack/lib/deck.rb:5:in `build_cards'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

2.1.1 :001 > require './card'
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > cards = Deck.build_cards
NameError: uninitialized constant Deck
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

If anyone could help clarify things for me it would be much appreciated. I have included the rest of the code below.

**card_spec.rb**

```
require 'card'
require 'deck'

describe Card do 

  it "should accept a suit and value when building" do 
    card = Card.new(:clubs, 10)
    expect(card.suit).to eq (:clubs)
    expect(card.value).to eq(10)
  end 

  it "should have a value of 10 for facecards" do 
    facecards = ["J", "Q", "K"]
    facecards.each do |facecard|
        card = Card.new(:hearts, facecard)
        expect(card.value).to eq(10)
    end
  end
  it "should have a value of 4 for the 4-clubs" do 
    card = Card.new(:clubs, 4)
    expect(card.value).to eq(4)
  end

  it "should return 11 for Ace" do 
    card = Card.new(:diamonds, "A")
    expect(card.value).to eq(11)
  end

  it "should be formatted nicely" do 
    card = Card.new(:diamonds, "A")
    expect(card.to_s).to eq("A-diamonds")
  end
end
```

**deck_spec.rb**

```
require 'card'
require 'deck'

describe Deck do 

    it 'should build 52 cards' do 
        expect(Deck.build_cards.length).to eq(52)
    end
end
```

**card.rb**

```
require 'deck'
class Card

    attr_reader :suit, :value
    def initialize(suit, value) 
        @suit = suit
        @value = value
        #the value here is what the card should return-facevalue
    end

    def value
        return 10 if ["J", "Q", "K"].include?(@value) 
        return 11 if @value == "A"
        return @value
    end

    def to_s
        "A-diamonds"
        "#{@value}-#{suit}"
    end
end
```

**deck.rb**

```
class Deck
    def self.build_cards
        cards = []
        [:clubs, :diamonds, :spades, :hearts].each do |suit|
            (2..10).each do |number|
            cards << Card.new(suit, number)
        end
        ["J", "Q", "K", "A"].each do |facecard|
            cards << Card.new(suit, facecard)
        end
    end
    cards
end
    #going to occur on the class as it is a class method and will execute once
    #The idea of a deck needs to be able to build a deck
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `require "card"` to `deck.rb`, since you reference `Card` in `.build_cards`. You will also need to add `lib` to your load path, since it is no longer done for you in Ruby. You can do this on the command-line:

```
irb -Ilib
ruby -Ilib
```

Note that `rspec` does this for you automatically, which is why your specs work.

If needed (say if you had a script in `bin` that you wanted to load files in `lib`) you can also do this in code.

```
# Assuming this code is in bin
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)
```

**Explanation of the load path**

The `-I` flag adds a directory to the `$LOAD_PATH` global variable. You can inspect this directly in your program:

```
> ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0
> ruby -Itesting -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'
/Users/xavier/Code/ex/ruby/testing
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0
/Users/xavier/.rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0
```

Notice how the second invocation contains the extra `testing` directory. If you did a similar test with IRB, you would see that without `-I` your `lib` directory is not in `$LOAD_PATH`, which is why it couldn't find your files to require.

Ruby uses this `$LOAD_PATH` variable to determine where to look when you require something. In pseudo-code:

```
def require(filename)
  $LOAD_PATH.each do |dir|
    path = File.join(dir, filename)
    if File.exist?(path)
      load(path)
      return
    end
  end
end
```

It's actually a bit more complicated (and efficient) than that, but that's the gist of it. If you're interested I [talked about it some at RubyConf 2013](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2860-rubyconf2013-profiling-ruby-finding-10x-gains-in-rspec-and-cruby).

**Other relevant points not directly answering your question:**

You should also remove `require "deck"` from `card.rb`, since nothing in that file needs to know about `Deck`. If you have warnings on, this would warn you about a "circular require", which is what happens if you have two files loading each other. This is generally a bad practice. (To be clear: that's not what you are doing here, since `card.rb` doesn't *actually* depend on `deck.rb`.

Your specs should only require the specific thing that is being tested. In this case, `card_spec.rb` should require card and `deck_spec.rb` should require deck. They don't need to each require both.

The `.rb` on your IRB require is redundant and not required.

Comment: Thanks this is such a clear answer it is much appreciated. I have followed what you suggested but then i get this                                                  require "deck"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- deck
 from /Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from /Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
 from (irb):3
 from /Users/em/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: It looks like you still need to run IRB with the `-I.` option. I'll move that up into the proper answer. If it's still not working, can you paste a copy of your terminal to me at https://gist.github.com ?

Comment: I am afraid it still does not work i shall try pasting over now!

Comment: my apologies, I misread your question. It should be `-Ilib` not `.`! I thought all your files were in the same directory, but you specified that they are not.

Comment: thanks, could you just clarify where i type this i am just a bit confused as this is not a command i have used before!

Comment: actually yes i do understand and it works! most appreciated! Could you just explain what this does?

Comment: Updated my answer with some more detail, hopefully that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69150/discussion-between-xavier-shay-and-emma).